# How do I write a google cloud dataflow transform mapping?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm upgrading a google cloud dataflow job from dataflow java sdk 1.8 to version 2.4 and then trying to update its existing dataflow job on google cloud using the --update and --transformNameMapping arguments, but I can't figure out how to properly write the transformNameMappings such that the upgrade succeeds and passes the compatibility check.

My code fails at the compatibility check with the error:

`Workflow failed. Causes: The new job is not compatible with 2018-04-06_13_48_04-12999941762965935736. The original job has not been aborted., The new job is missing steps BigQueryIO.writeTableRows/BigQueryIO.StreamWithDeDup/Reshuffle/GroupByKey, PubsubIO.readStrings. If these steps have been renamed or deleted, please specify them with the update command.`

The dataflow transform names for the existing, currently running job are:

1. PubsubIO.Read
2. ParDo(ExtractJsonPath) - A custom function we wrote
3. ParDo(AddMetadata) - Another custom function we wrote
4. BigQueryIO.Write

In my new code that uses the 2.4 sdk, I've changed the 1st and 4th transforms/functions because of some libraries being renamed and deprecation of some of the old sdk's functions in the new version.

You can see the specific transform code below:

The 1.8 SDK version:

```
     PCollection<String> streamData =
       pipeline
        .apply(PubsubIO.Read
                .timestampLabel(PUBSUB_TIMESTAMP_LABEL_KEY)
                 //.subscription(options.getPubsubSubscription())
                .topic(options.getPubsubTopic()));
     streamData
         .apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractJsonPathFn(pathInfos)))
         .apply(ParDo.of(new AddMetadataFn()))
        .apply(BigQueryIO.Write
                 .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                 .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                 .to(tableRef)
```

The 2.4 SDK version I rewrote:

```
     PCollection<String> streamData =
       pipeline
        .apply("PubsubIO.readStrings", PubsubIO.readStrings()
                .withTimestampAttribute(PUBSUB_TIMESTAMP_LABEL_KEY)
                 //.subscription(options.getPubsubSubscription())
                .fromTopic(options.getPubsubTopic()));

     streamData
         .apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractJsonPathFn(pathInfos)))
         .apply(ParDo.of(new AddMetadataFn()))
        .apply("BigQueryIO.writeTableRows", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                 .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                 .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                 .to(tableRef)
```

So it seems to me like `PubsubIO.Read` should map to `PubsubIO.readStrings` and `BigQueryIO.Write` should map to `BigQueryIO.writeTableRows`. But I could be misunderstanding how this works.

I've been trying a wide variety of things - I tried to give those two transforms that I'm failing to remap defined names as they formerly were not explicity named, so I updated my applys to  `.apply("PubsubIO.readStrings"` and `.apply("BigQueryIO.writeTableRows"` and then set my transformNameMapping argument to:

```
--transformNameMapping={\"BigQueryIO.Write\":\"BigQueryIO.writeTableRows\",\"PubsubIO.Read\":\"PubsubIO.readStrings\"}
```

or

```
 --transformNameMapping={\"BigQueryIO.Write/BigQueryIO.StreamWithDeDup/Reshuffle/GroupByKey\":\"BigQueryIO.writeTableRows/BigQueryIO.StreamWithDeDup/Reshuffle/GroupByKey\",\"PubsubIO.Read\":\"PubsubIO.readStrings\"}
```

or even trying to remap all the internal transforms inside the composite transform

```
--transformNameMapping={\"BigQueryIO.Write/BigQueryIO.StreamWithDeDup/Reshuffle/GroupByKey\":\"BigQueryIO.writeTableRows/BigQueryIO.StreamWithDeDup/Reshuffle/GroupByKey\",\"BigQueryIO.Write/BigQueryIO.StreamWithDeDup/Reshuffle\":\"BigQueryIO.writeTableRows/BigQueryIO.StreamWithDeDup/Reshuffle\",\"BigQueryIO.Write/BigQueryIO.StreamWithDeDup\":\"BigQueryIO.writeTableRows/BigQueryIO.StreamWithDeDup\",\"BigQueryIO.Write\":\"BigQueryIO.writeTableRows\",\"PubsubIO.Read\":\"PubsubIO.readStrings\"}
```

but I seem to get the same exact error no matter what:

```
The new job is missing steps BigQueryIO.writeTableRows/BigQueryIO.StreamWithDeDup/Reshuffle/GroupByKey, PubsubIO.readStrings.
```

Wondering if I'm doing something seriously wrong? Anybody whose written a transform mapping before who would be willing to share the format they used? I can't find any examples online at all besides the main google documentation on updating dataflow jobs which doesn't really cover anything but the most simple case `--transformNameMapping={"oldTransform1":"newTransform1","oldTransform2":"newTransform2",...}` and doesn't make the example very concrete.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there was additional information in the logs in the google cloud web console dataflow job details page that I was missing. I needed to adjust the log level from `info` to show `any log level` and then I found several step fusion messages like for example (although there were far more):

```
 2018-04-16 (13:56:28) Mapping original step BigQueryIO.Write/BigQueryIO.StreamWithDeDup/Reshuffle/GroupByKey to write/StreamingInserts/StreamingWriteTables/Reshuffle/GroupByKey in the new graph.
 2018-04-16 (13:56:28) Mapping original step PubsubIO.Read to PubsubIO.Read/PubsubUnboundedSource in the new graph.
```

Instead of trying to map `PubsubIO.Read` to `PubsubIO.readStrings` I needed to map to the steps that I found mentioned in that additional logging. In this case I got past my errors by mapping `PubsubIO.Read` to `PubsubIO.Read/PubsubUnboundedSource` and `BigQueryIO.Write/BigQueryIO.StreamWithDeDup` to `BigQueryIO.Write/StreamingInserts/StreamingWriteTables`. So try mapping your old steps to those that are mentioned in the full logs before the job failure message in the logs.

Unfortunately I'm not working through a failure of the compatibility check due to a change in the coder used from the old code to the new code, but my `missing step` errors are solved.